# Footer not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I set a white footer of 30px height on my webpage. For some reason when I scroll down the page the footer gets much higher than that and the text part (div with light grey background) overlap it.
Would you know what's wrong and how to fix this?
Jsfiddle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/AdX3m/
Many thanks

Here is a screenshot

[image]

CSS

```
    @charset"UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: 100;
}
Html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 35px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#header-text {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:300;
    color: #FFF;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #0063C3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #0063C3 0%, #2E88C9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #0063C3), color-stop(100%, #2E88C9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #0063C3 0%, #2E88C9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #0063C3 0%, #2E88C9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #0063C3 0%, #2E88C9 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0063C3 0%, #2E88C9 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0063C3', endColorstr='#2E88C9', GradientType=1 )
}


#footer {
    position: fixed; /* Force it to stick to the bottom*/
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
}

/* mainmenu */

#mainmenu {
    width: 100%;
    /* min-height: 180px; */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -42px; 
    /* padding-top: -42px; */
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    color: #000;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
#mainmenu>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li a, #mainmenu ul ul:hover li a {
    color: #fff;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all, transform;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #005EBC;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all, transform;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
}
p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:justify;
    font-weight:300;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    }

H5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div#content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    background: lightblue;
}
div#content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
div#content-center {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Document sans nom</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="logo">My Name</div>
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu I</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Biography</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Publications</a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 2</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Demo</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Features</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Comparison</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 3</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 1</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 2</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 3</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 4</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">ddfd</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">dsfd</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- END DIV Main Menu -->

    <div id="header-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.</div>

    <div id="content-left">column1</div>
    <div id="content-right">
      <h1>Novitates autem si spem</h1>
      <p>Novitates autem si spem adferunt, ut tamquam in herbis non fallacibus
        fructus appareat, non sunt illae quidem repudiandae, vetustas tamen suo
        loco conservanda; maxima est enim vis vetustatis et consuetudinis. Quin
        in ipso equo, cuius modo feci mentionem, si nulla res impediat, nemo est,
        quin eo, quo consuevit, libentius utatur quam intractato et novo. Nec vero
        in hoc quod est animal, sed in iis etiam quae sunt inanima, consuetudo
        valet, cum locis ipsis delectemur, montuosis etiam et silvestribus, in
        quibus diutius commorati sumus.</p>
      <p>Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox
        interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius,
        modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.</p>
      <p>Duplexque isdem diebus acciderat malum, quod et Theophilum insontem atrox
        interceperat casus, et Serenianus dignus exsecratione cunctorum, innoxius,
        modo non reclamante publico vigore, discessit.</p>
      <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans
        terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem
        sed sibi vicissim velut ad perpendiculum aemulas: Caesaream, quam ad honorem
        Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim
        itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>
      <p>Itaque verae amicitiae difficillime reperiuntur in iis qui in honoribus
        reque publica versantur; ubi enim istum invenias qui honorem amici anteponat
        suo? Quid? Haec ut omittam, quam graves, quam difficiles plerisque videntur
        calamitatum societates! Ad quas non est facile inventu qui descendant.
        Quamquam Ennius recte.</p>
              <p>Itaque verae amicitiae difficillime reperiuntur in iis qui in honoribus
        reque publica versantur; ubi enim istum invenias qui honorem amici anteponat
        suo? Quid? Haec ut omittam, quam graves, quam difficiles plerisque videntur
        calamitatum societates! Ad quas non est facile inventu qui descendant.
        Quamquam Ennius recte.</p>
              <p>Itaque verae amicitiae difficillime reperiuntur in iis qui in honoribus
        reque publica versantur; ubi enim istum invenias qui honorem amici anteponat
        suo? Quid? Haec ut omittam, quam graves, quam difficiles plerisque videntur
        calamitatum societates! Ad quas non est facile inventu qui descendant.         reque publica versantur; ubi enim istum invenias qui honorem amici anteponat
        suo? Quid? Haec ut omittam, quam graves, quam difficiles plerisque videntur
        calami
        Quamquam Ennius recte.</p>
              <p>Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans
        terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem
        sed sibi vicissim velut ad perpendiculum aemulas: Caesaream, quam ad honorem
        Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim
        itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas.</p>
      <p>Itaque verae amicitiae difficillime reperiuntur in iis qui in honoribus
        reque publica versantur; ubi enim istum invenias qui honorem amici anteponat
        suo? Quid? Haec ut omittam, quam graves, quam difficiles plerisque videntur
        calamitatum societates! Ad quas non est facile inventu qui descendant.
        Quamquam Ennius recte. END END END</p>
    </div>

  <div id="footer">Test Footer</div>
  <!-- END DIV Footer --> 
</div>
<!-- END DIV Wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're talking about; is this specific to a browser?

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using? Can't reproduce with Firefox 19

Comment: Hi - Using Safari, latest version. Have added a screenshot of the prob to my original post. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of your footer doesn't change as you scroll down, it stays the same. The problem lies with your element heights, particularly `#wrap`, which affects the `background-color` styles that you have set...

Instead of setting the background colour styles in `#wrap`, you can try setting them for `body`

```
body { background: #0063C3; ... }
```

This might fix the problem you've described.

Answer (score 1):

delete from the style footer

```
position:fixed;
```

or change some height value or font size if you want the footer to stick to the bottom